# Python PyGSM \x00 received SMS

Tags: python, sms, escaping

I'm using pygsm to receive sms from python, to store into the database. But when an email address is received, it appears as "thisemail\x00gmail.com". And therefore, it stores

```
thisemail\x00gmail.com
```

into the database. How do i make it so that it stores

```
thisemail@gmail.com
```

I've been trying it for days by replacing and splitting the string..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the str.replace method

```
a='thisemail\x00gmail.com'
a=a.replace('\x00','@') 
print("%s"%a)
```